# Conflicting constraints on GIDSignInButton in Google Sign-In SDK 2.0.1

Tags: ios, google-signin

I'm trying to upgrade from Google Sign-In SDK 1.0.0 to 2.0.1 and ran into some conflicting constraints when trying to position an instance of the `GIDSignInButton`.

It seems like `GIDSignInButton` may define its own dynamic constrains which conflict with the ones I set in Interface Builder. I'm not able to verify this since the SDK is closed source.

The constraint warning can actually be reproduced with Google's own sample code on https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/81c831d85a67157746009fa2df81a683f860d21e/ios/signin.

Is there a work around to position this button or is this just a bug in SDK 2.0.1?

---

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e0064b650 V:[UIView:0x7f9e0064b360(198)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e0064b830 UIView:0x7f9e0064b360.centerY == GIDSignInButton.centerY   (Names: GIDSignInButton:0x7f9e0046f000 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e006603c0 h=--& v=--& GIDSignInButton.midY == + 97   (Names: GIDSignInButton:0x7f9e0046f000 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e0064b830 UIView:0x7f9e0064b360.centerY == GIDSignInButton.centerY   (Names: GIDSignInButton:0x7f9e0046f000 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

---

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e00476cd0 GIDSignInButton.width == 3.26531*GIDSignInButton.height   (Names: GIDSignInButton:0x7f9e0046f000 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e00476f20 H:[GIDSignInButton(160)]   (Names: GIDSignInButton:0x7f9e0046f000 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e00660410 h=--& v=--& V:[GIDSignInButton(44)]   (Names: GIDSignInButton:0x7f9e0046f000 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e00476cd0 GIDSignInButton.width == 3.26531*GIDSignInButton.height   (Names: GIDSignInButton:0x7f9e0046f000 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

---

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e0064b7e0 UIView:0x7f9e0064b360.centerX == GIDSignInButton.centerX   (Names: GIDSignInButton:0x7f9e0046f000 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e00657480 H:[UIView:0x7f9e0064b360]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f9e0064b050 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e006574d0 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f9e0064b360]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f9e0064b050 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e0065dda0 h=--& v=--& GIDSignInButton.midX == + 207   (Names: GIDSignInButton:0x7f9e0046f000 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e0046d5e0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7f9e0064b050(375)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e0064b7e0 UIView:0x7f9e0064b360.centerX == GIDSignInButton.centerX   (Names: GIDSignInButton:0x7f9e0046f000 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: Have you tried to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO` for your button?

Comment: Sega-Zero: Good suggestion. I just tried `signInButton.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)` but it didn't seem to help. Is there anyway to set that property from IB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has fixed this bug in Google Sign-In SDK 2.1.0 (released on 6/17/2015).

> Fixes Auto Layout issues with GIDSignInButton.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the solution I found was to embed the google sign-in button in another view and set the constraints on the container.
the only constraints i gave to the GIDSignInButton instance was center (x,y) in container cause otherwise it will still be shifted to the right.

I hope this helps